# Shortest Path Algorithm for Simulations

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

We have a program that has a map with obstacles and people in it. The people are in random places and each has random weight. We used the Triangulation A*  algorithm for them to find the shortest path to a certain destination. For every second, their speed and coordinates are logged. Collisions are possible when they are running.

Now we plan to simulate that program 100 times. For each simulation, the map, the destination, and the number of people and their weight are the same. The difference is the path where they will go-- say different algorithms are run. Some simulations may have more collisions on a particular area, others may have the people take a longer path but with minimal collisions. We want to make the **pathfinding logic of the people to be smarter**. Given the data that we have from the logs of the simulations, what machine learning algorithm can we use to find the best path based on the map with obstacles?

Comment: How can they rund different paths if they all use the "shortest path"?

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone you know. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question and get it re-opened.

Comment: What you're asking for is an introductory tutorial (or the results of such an overview) on classes of Machine Learning algorithms and their applications.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: @MrSmith42: They aren't all running the shortest path; the people are elements of the `Triangulation A*` process.  They're used to converge on the shortest path.